# Fail to find sonarqube while using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I m using jenkins and I need my sonarqube to make some analysis on my code.

I use docker to manage both images and mapped the port so that they are accessible from outside. It works great, I can open and login in both portals.

My problem is that when I try to run my jenkins build and ask sonarqube for informations, it throws me the following error :

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:101)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:198)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:358)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:114)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Execute SonarQube Scanner' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know at all what's going wrong here.

**What I did :**

- I have registered a server key in the "user=>token=>generate a token for user" in sonarqube and use it inside of my jenkins app

Comment: It might be downloading the libraries mentioned in the stacktrace using some other port than what you've mapped for Docker currently.

Comment: Did anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your Jenkins server can't access your sonar server. Maybe the IP or domain is set wrong. Maybe the networking between them isn't set up correctly.

Somewhere in your Jenkins console log you should see something like this:

```
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: Sonarqube Local
[workspace] $ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.yourserver.com -Dsonar.login=******
```

Make sure that this sonar.host.url is set correctly. Then make sure you can access this from your jenkins server.